# displaying even and odd numbers in an array

Tags: javascript

Given two numbers X and Y, write a function that:
1. returns even numbers between X and Y, if X is greater than Y else it returns odd numbers between x and y
For instance, take the integers 10 and 2 . the function would return all the even numbers between 2 and 10

i'm new to JavaScript this is what i have tried so far.

```
const number_game = (x, y) => {


// Code here

  let numArray = [];

  let numArray2 = []

  if(x < y){

        for (i=x+1; i<y; i++) {
            if (i%2 != 0) {
                numArray.push(i);
            }else {
              numArray2.push(i)
            }
        }
    }

  else{

    if(x > y){

      for (i=y+1; i<x; i++) {
            if (i%2 != 0) {
                numArray.push(i);
            }else {
              numArray2.push(i)
            }
        }
    }
    } return numArray

 }
```

i get this error Below

expected `[ Array(9) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ]`

Comment: What purpose does `numArray2` serve? Do you even need the `else` block? But more importantly, both loops have identical contents, surely a sign that something is wrong. Additionally, why are you looping between `x+1` and `<y` when you should be looping between `x` and `<=y`?

Comment: Maybe between `2` and `10` means including `2` and `10`.

Comment: the function would return all the even numbers between 2 and 10

Comment: No error is showing up. Can you specify which browser is showing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The variables x and y are first compared to each other inside an if statement. When x is larger the for loop for even numbers is run from y to x. If the number is found to be divisible by 2 it is put inside an array. If y>x then for loop for odd numbers run from x to y. If the number is not divisible by 2 means it is odd and it is pushed inside the array. The array is printed.

```js
var x=2;
var y=10;
arr=[];
if(x>y)
{
  for(let i=y;i<x;i++)
  {
    if(i%2==0)
    arr.push(i);
  }
}
else
{
  for(let i=x;i<y;i++)
  {
    if(i%2==1)
    arr.push(i);
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Explain your code. What does it do, and why should it work? Don't expect people to just blindly run code they found on the internet. ... Actually people do that all the time, and it's terrible, but that's not the point. Just pasting code with no explanation doesn't help anyone to learn, and learning is the whole point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks but it still shows this error:   expected [ Array(10) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ]

Answer (score 0):

Tells me if it works. I have added explanation

```
function number_game(x,y){
    let resultArr = []; //The array which will be returned
    //To return all even numbers x and y
    if(x>y){
        //checks if y(smaller number) and make it even
        if(y % 2 != 0 ) y+=1
        //Now y is even and by add 2 each loop it will get all even to result arr
        for(let i = y;i<x;i+=2){
            resultArr.push(i);
        }
    }
    //To return all even odd x and y
    else{
        //checks if x(smaller number) and odd it even
        if(x % 2 == 0 ) x+=1
        //Now x is odd and by add 2 each loop it will get all odds to result arr
        for(let i = x; i<y; i+=2){
            resultArr.push(i);
        }
    }
    return resultArr;

}
console.log(number_game(2,10)) //[3, 5, 7, 9]
console.log(number_game(10,2)) //[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Explain your code. What does it do, and why should it work? Don't expect people to just blindly run code they found on the internet. ... Actually people do that all the time, and it's terrible, but that's not the point. Just pasting code with no explanation doesn't help anyone to learn, and learning is the whole point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks but it still shows this error:   expected [ Array(10) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ]

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol He asked that he if `x>y` he wanna return all the odd values b/w `x` and `y`. And if  `x<y` he wants to return all odd numbers b/w `x` and `y`. Am I right?

Comment: `returns even numbers between X and Y, if X is greater than Y else it returns odd numbers between x and y` Seems clear to me.

Comment: @innocent igwonobe I didn't see any errors. Please give your so we could help you

Answer (score 0):

So here the idea is first we check `start` and `end`.
if `start` is less than `end` than inside if condition we check `start` whether it is even or not if it is even we keep it as it is if not we add 1 to it.
In while loop we keeping pushing `start` to final output and adding 2 to start and until it is less than `end`. and in else we check for odd and rest process is same.

```js
function giveMeNumbers(start,end){
  let op = []
  if(start < end) {
    start = start % 2 ? start++ : start;
    while(start < end){
      op.push(start);
      start+=2
    }
  } else {
    end = end%2 ? end : end++;
    while(start > end){
      op.push(end);
      end+=2
    }
  }
  
  return op;
}

console.log(giveMeNumbers(1,11))
console.log(giveMeNumbers(22,10))
```

Comment: `start = start % 2 ? start++ : start` I feel personally attacked by this line. Why not `if( start%2) start++;`? Much clearer what's being done...

Comment: However it doesn't matter that much since this code - given without any explanation - utterly fails the second half of the requirement which is that if `end > start` it should instead return odd numbers.

Comment: Explain your code. What does it do, and why should it work? Don't expect people to just blindly run code they found on the internet. ... Actually people do that all the time, and it's terrible, but that's not the point. Just pasting code with no explanation doesn't help anyone to learn, and learning is the whole point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol well that's about personal preference. and yeah i missed the second part. added now and updated with explanantion

Comment: `start = start++` is ambiguous and entirely unclear. Sorry but that's not personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

If *x > y* all **even** numbers are returned, else if *x < y* all **odd** numbers are returned

```
const number_game = (x, y) => {
    let range;
    if (x > y) {
        range = Array(x - y + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => y + idx)
        return range.filter(num => !(num % 2))
    } else{
        range = Array(y - x + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => x + idx)
        return range.filter(num => (num % 2))
    }
}

console.log('x > y ', number_game(22,10)); // [ 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22 ]​​​​​
console.log('x < y ', number_game(2,10)); // ​​​​​[ 3, 5, 7, 9 ]​​​​​
```

Comment: He said **bewteen** `x` and `y` so it should include `10` and `22`  i think

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `Generator`s:

```js
function * generateNumbers (start, stop) {
  let x = start;
  while(x <= stop) {
    yield x;
    x = x + 1;
  }
}

function * filterGen (f, gen) {
  for (const x of gen) {
    if (f(x)) { yield x; }
  }
}

const isEven = x => x % 2 === 0;
const isOdd = x => !isEven(x);

const makeNum = (a, b) => {
  if (a <= b) {
    return [...filterGen(isEven, generateNumbers(a, b))];
  }
  return [...filterGen(isOdd, generateNumbers(b, a))];
}


console.log('Evens 1 through 10:', makeNum(1, 10));
console.log('Odds 1 through 10:', makeNum(10, 1));
```

The `generateNumbers` function produces a sequence of all integers between `start` and `stop`. For example:

```
generateNumbers(1, 3); // -> 1, 2, 3
```

The resulting generator is then passed into the `filterGen`, which itself is a generator again. `filterGen` takes a function and another generator, and only `yield`s the values for which the (predicate) function returned `true`.

```
filterGen(x => x === 2, generateNumbers(1, 3)); // -> 2
```

`isEven` and `isOdd` are just predicate functions for the `filterGen` function.

Inside `makeNum` (should be `makeNumbers` though), only check if the incoming `a` is less than or equals to the `b` and produces a new `Array` from the filtered integer sequences.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to your solution, explanation is inside the code, I have tried to simplify the code all I could, any recommendations are welcome.

```js
const number_game = (x, y) =>
{
    let arr = [];

    // Depending of x > y condition, create the test method.
    // "test" will be a function that will check for even
    // number when x > y, otherwise will check for odd numbers.
    
    let test = (x > y) ? (n) => !Boolean(n % 2) : (n) => Boolean(n % 2);

    // Based on x > y condition, define the init and end number.

    let [init, end] = (x > y) ? [y, x] : [x, y];
    !test(init) && init++;

    // Generate evens/odds number between init and end.

    while (init <= end)
    {
        arr.push(init), init += 2;
    }

    return arr;
}

// Test cases.

console.log(JSON.stringify(number_game(1, 10)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(number_game(10, 1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(number_game(10, 0)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(number_game(-3, 13)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(number_game(9, 9)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(number_game(9, 8)));
```